# Drag application window to another space

Tags: spaces

In OS X Mavericks how do I drag a window to another space?  I was able to do this in Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Go to system preferences -> Mission Control and uncheck "Displays have separate Spaces"

Now logout and login.

You now should be able to drag your windows between spaces like in (Mountain) Lion.

Comment: I presume this answer implies that dragging a window between spaces is not possible when "Displays have separate Spaces" is checked? It isn't clear to me why these functions are mutually exclusive =/

Answer (score 0):

**Simply drag the window to the edge of the screen and hold it there for about a second.**
The space slides to the side and you can drop the window into that space.

Alternatively, you can open Mission Control and drag the window to an existing space or directly to a new space by dragging it to the new space button in the top right.

Comment: Right.  I am trying to do the drag, but with Mavericks I waited longer than 1 second and nothing is happening.

Comment: Yes, space exists.  I am running dual monitors.  I am on space one and trying to drag safari (not full screen) to the right to jump to space two.